# detect a click on another userControl than the current one

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have created a session selector for a project.
The sessions are represented by userControl and its dynamically positioned in a panel

I would like that when I press a UserControl of a session, this one changes it backColor into a color and that when another userControl than this one is selected that the color is removed on the current userControl and put on the new one

I don't know if it's very clear, but here's what I tried to do:

```
private void UserControl_Seance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isClicked = true;
    this.BackColor = Color.Blue;          
}
```

But the code stops there because I have no idea how to detect a click on another UserControl than this one

Does anyone have a solution to detect a click on another userControl than the current one? Thank you.

Comment: Assign the click events of all the user controls to the same handler. In there, cast sender to a user control and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I'll try that in an hour, thank you for your answer!